# What to do with a winforms app that looks poor with medium/large fonts enabled on windows 7?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, large-fonts

I have a windows forms app built with .NET 3.5 and a relatively old version of Infragistics controls. It turns out some of the forms/controls look quite poor when viewed in Windows7 and Medium or Large Fonts. What are my options to resolve this? I have some tens of forms and would like a short-term solution rather than a rewrite, as the app will be migrated to WPF or Silverlight in the medium term.

Is there a switch I can 'turn off' medium/large fonts for the app as an immediate fix?

What general principles need to be followed for winforms apps to render nicely with medium/large fonts turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far the main things I've found I needed to do are:

- Change forms/controls so AutoScaleMode is set to Font
- Change any forms with programmatic resizing so they're dependent on other controls' size or position, rather than hard-coded numbers that are right if fonts are set to normal size.

Other than that things mostly work as desired. Mostly. Still the odd odd thing to track down.

Comment: If you change the form's `AutoScaleMode` to "Font", any controls it contains should automatically inherit the value of that property. This is the best answer I could have given to your question without knowing what other problems you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the AutoScaleMode suggestion.

I redesigned all the forms into TableLayoutPanels (it took ages) and got set all my Labels to `AutoResize = True`. TableLayouts take most of the pain away. Scaling and alignment are a breeze, although they are quite slow compared to say WPF.